# Why are the changes in my code being reflected without having to restart the server?

Tags: node.js, express

After running `node app.js` in the OS X Terminal to start the server, any file that has its contents altered in the editor and then saved will have the changes immediately reflected when I refresh the `localhost:3000` page, even when the server has not been restarted (so far, I have tried this on *.ejs, .css* and *.js* files).

Details:

- Problem only happens in one directory; I am unable to replicate it in another similarly structured sibling directory.
- I do not have Nodemon/Forever/Node Supervisor installed, as far as I know.
- I tried `killall node` (I thought that I had nothing to lose as this should have been the only process running on my computer; I now realise that this may have been the wrong approach)
- I have already tried restarting the computer but to no avail; the problem still persists.
- When I do stop the application, the `localhost:3000` page shows that "This site can’t be reached", i.e. the server can and has been stopped.

Why do I not need to stop (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) then restart (<kbd>⇧</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>) the application every time I save a file in the editor? What is going on here and how I could replicate it or make it stop?

Comment: It seems the files you have edited so far are client side files which doesn't require the node process to be restarted

Comment: @danielnetto oh man, I spent up to two hours on this and your one-line answer seems to be the right one. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML,CSS and frontend JS modifications do not require you to restart your node process as they are read on every request, unlike your server side code that is loaded in memory as soon as you start up your server.

Basically what happens is that when you run your server side JS like app.js it loads in memory and any code in that file will stay in memory as long as the process is running, when you serve a html file your framework reads the html file every time a request is received, due to which changes to html file are reflected every-time without you having to restart your server , as well as JS changes in your html file are reflected as they are not part of server side process. On every request your process opens the html file reads its content and sends to browser using HTTP protocol and your browser reads your html response and request your server for necessary JS files included in your html which are in your public folder.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you be able to point me to where I can read up more about this as I have tried and failed to Google an answer and there is no mention of this in the tutorial I'm following.

Comment: i couldn't find more info on this myself, i will improve my answer a bit for you

Comment: i have updated my answer, feel free to ask any question i will try to help as much as i can